# Changing JQuery version has broken jquery fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I've updated my website to use Bootstrap and the version I'm using needs to use **jQuery Version 1.11.0**. However, doing this has broken Jquery Fancybox v. 1.3.4... the images no longer pop up in a dialogue box, but redirect to a new page.

When I change the jquery back to **jQuery Version Library v1.3.2** my fancybox works, but the bootstrap doesn't!

Please help!! I can't find any way to fix this.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS - Uses Bootswatch Flatly Theme: http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ -->
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Fancybox for gallery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <!-- bespoke JQuery functions -->
   <script src="js/bespokeJS.js"></script>
   <!-- CSS jQuery Fancybox for gallery -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> 
     <script type="text/javascript">
// FANCY BOX
    $(function() {
        $("a.group").fancybox({
            'nextEffect'    :   'fade',
            'prevEffect'    :   'fade',
            'overlayOpacity' :  0.8,
            'overlayColor' : '#000000',
            'arrows' : true,
            });         
        });
   </script>
 </head>
<body id="gallery" class="gallery" >

<!-- Start split screen LEFT COLUMN -->
<div id="mainRed">  
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div id="leftCol" class="leftCol col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 well">
    <div id="leftColContentContainer" >
    <div id="leftColTitleDiv" ></div>

      //gets images from instagram page
      <?php
                            // Supply a user id and an access token
                            $userid = "xxx";
                            $accessToken = "xxxx";

                            // Gets our data
                            function fetchData($url){
                                 $ch = curl_init();
                                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
                                 $result = curl_exec($ch);
                                 curl_close($ch); 
                                 return $result;
                            }

                            // Pulls and parses data.
                            $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}");
                            $result = json_decode($result);
                        ?>
                        <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
                            <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
                            <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img style="padding-left:10px; padding-top: 10px;" src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
                        <?php endforeach ?>     

    </div><!-- close left column container -->
    </div> <!-- close left column -->
    </div> <!-- close row -->
   </div> <!-- close container -->
    </div><!-- close main -->
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: ahh, `jQuery` lib is not causing an issue, instead the bootstrap library due to possible conflict in the ui classes of `bootstrap` & `fancybox`. could you replicate the same on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Update to new fancybox - version is now 2.1.5 and you can use the latest version of jQuery with it: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/.  V 1.3.4 is very old and shouldn't be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old fancyBox is not [compatible with new jQuery](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/485) versions.

You have two options. Downgrade jQuery which I think you don't want to do or upgrade [fancyBox](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license).

or [this patch](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/incompatibility-between-jquery-191-and-fancybox-134) might be useful.